# Cakephp 4.x CMS tutorial authentication redirect problem

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I just recreated the CMS tutorial to the letter. When not logged in and trying to edit an article I'm redirected to the login page. Success here.
After logging in I get redirected to an error page. Why? The redirect back to articles has gone wrong. See below

Link it is redirecting to: http://localhost/**test_cms/test_cms**/articles/edit/first-post

Link it is supposed to redirect to http://localhost/**test_cms**/articles/edit/first-post

I worked every file according to the CMS tutorial and can't seem to figure out what is going wrong here.

Login code below:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->Authorization->skipAuthorization();

    $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);
    $result = $this->Authentication->getResult();
    // regardless of POST or GET, redirect if user is logged in
    if ($result->isValid()) {
        // redirect to /articles after login success
        $redirect = $this->request->getQuery('redirect', [
            'controller' => 'Articles',
            'action' => 'index',
        ]);
        return $this->redirect($redirect);
    }
    // display error if user submitted and authentication failed
    if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password'));
    }
}
```

Error screenshot: https://ibb.co/PjX8435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue as well and found a work around.  In my UsersController login method, before `return $this->redirect($redirect);`, I added this code to strip the extra app name:

```
if (!is_array($redirect)) {
   if (strncmp($redirect, '/myapp', 6) === 0) {
     $redirect = substr($redirect, 6);
   }
  }
```

Again, this is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've set extra `test_cms` somewhere in your code or the URL for unauthorized action might be appending extra `test_cms` in your `redirect` query params. You can debug it by printing `$redirect` variable inside `if` condition.

Also you may want to add some screenshot, error message, stack trace along with your question which can help people understand the problem to get more accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The link test_cms is never set in the code itself. I just unboxed the basis of CakePHP in the directory and went through the tutorial. Attached is the screenshot.
![IMAGE](https://ibb.co/PjX8435).

Comment: If it's not set in your code so as I've mentioned you should check `$redirect` variable. Have you printed `$redirect` variable? What does it contains? The URL is set properly in that as needed?